# Strange behavior while terminating a python process

Tags: python, bash

I have a process which needs to be killed.

```
python /foo/bar/bz
```

I currently use:

```
    ps -aux | grep bz

sudo kill -9 {{Process ID}}
```

This works, however i tried using :

```
sudo pkill bz
```

but this fails. I am not sure why i see this strange behaviour

I would not like to use `pkill python` as there are other python processes which are running, which i ideally donot want to disturb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-f` option:

```
sudo pkill -f bz
```

According to `pkill(1)` manpage:

> ```
> -f, --full
>
>       The pattern is normally only matched against the  process  name.
>       When -f is set, the full command line is used.
> ```

**NOTE** Above command will kill any process that contains `bz` in command line. So make sure you do not kill unexpected process by issuing `pgrep -fl bz`